# Python decorators

Tags: python, closures, decorator

I have a question about decorators. I understand what are decorators and I know how to use it, I have read all this tutorial [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python?lq=1)

I understand that :

```
>>> def my_decorator(fn):
>>>     print 'Do something before'
>>>     print fn()


>>> def foo():
>>>     return 'Hello World!'

>>> foo = my_decorator(foo)
```

Is the same at that :

```
>>> def my_decorator(fn):
>>>     print 'Do something before'
>>>     print fn()

>>> @my_decorator
>>> def foo():
>>>     return 'Hello World!'
```

I know what are closures and why we use closure in a decorator with parameters (to get the decorator parameters in nested function) but that I don't understand is why we use closure and nested functions to get arguments and the function.

How the closure (or something else) can access parameters and the function outside. I am unable to do the same without the @decorator.

Here for example I can access my foo() and the parameters of the function without passing this function in parameter :

```
def my_decorator(str):
    def wrapper(fn):
        def inner_function(*args):
            print 'Do something before'
            return fn(*args)
        return inner_function
    return wrapper

@my_decorator('test')
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b


print foo(1, 1)
```

How this is possible ?

Comment: Because that's what a decorator does. It's not a simple function call, it's a decorator, and it gets passed the function below it as the first argument (and the returned function replaces it).

Comment: It's not magic exactly - it's like asking why the brackets after a function call it - it's a documented part of the language.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable to do the same without the @decorator"? Please give an example.

Comment: As in the first example  I can see what is a decorator

Comment: You can do `foo = my_decorator('test')(foo)`, as an alternative to the `@` syntax.

Comment: Thanks this helped I posted the solution

Comment: You are slightly wrong about how decorators work; `@decorator def foo()...` is equivalent to `foo = decorator(foo)`, not just `decorator(foo)`. (Which is pretty much what Janne says).

Comment: Thanks it's was just for me to see the result. I know that it used to modify the function at the definition. So it should replace my function definition. I edited my question. Thanks for pointed that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution :

In fact the decorator use the closure functionality :
So here is the solution to do the same thing without the decorator and with parameters (it's just to understand the operation, and to learn)

```
def wrapper(str):
    def decorator_factory(fn):
        def inner_function(*args):
            print 'Do something before'
            return fn(*args)
        return inner_function
    return decorator_factory

@my_decorator('test')
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b

# with decorator
print foo(1, 1)

# without decorator
print wrapper('str')(foo)(1, 1)
```

Comment: Another way to look at it is: `the_actual_decorator = my_decorator('some_string')`. You see, the function `my_decorator()` is somewhat poorly named (for this example) because it is not really a decorator per se, but a wrapper that returns a decorator with a closure. This *returned* decorator is the one that is applied to `foo()`.

Comment: So I have to name my_decorator() in wrapper() ?

Answer (score -1):

Decorator is a function that takes one argument (this argument is function) - this is my definition of decorator. In your case `wrapper` is decorator. While `my_decorator` is used to collect arguments for `inner_function`. `inner_function` is used to replace original [not decorated] function. Step by step explanation would be:

1. `my_decorator` is called to collect options for `inner_function`
2. `my_decorator` returns `wrapper`
3. `wrapper` is responsible for capturing original function or in other words decorate it. In your case original function is `foo`.
4. `wrapper` returns replacement function for original (which is `inner_function`)
5. from now `foo` points to `inner_function`, therefore `inner_function` is executed then `foo` is called

Hope it makes things a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks your comment helped me to find how the decorator call all the functions